# Spell Checking File Names

Tags: windows, filenames, spell-check

How can I spell check file names?  My spelling isn't at all great, and I rely on MS Word, Google Chrome etc. to make sure I don't publically embarass myself with improper spelling.

How can I clean up my file and folder names? Is there a program or app I can use?

Comment: What is the number of names you are talking about? Ten? Hundred? Thousands? Maybe sorting them and looking them up in a dictionary manually could be easier and faster (maybe also safer) rather then trying to automate the "fixing".

Answer (score 1):

You can list the file and folder names using Directory Lister freeware available @ http://www.freesoftwaretools.net/sites/default/files/DirLister.rar and then carry out a spell check on the extracted listing of file and folder names without extensions by copying it into Microsoft Word.

Comment: Yes, but how do I then automatically rename the incorrectly named file names, to correctly named ones?

Comment: In the end no program knows your intention, so there is no automatic decision for "right or wrong"; automatic corrections can make things worse, actually. In many cases it's not clear which of multiple alternatives is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

[ispell](http://www.projectory.de/ispell/) or [aspell](http://aspell.net/win32/)?

something like (untested)

```
c:\> dir /B | ispell -l
```

or

```
c:\> dir /B | aspell -list
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  where do I enter this, what do I do with this, what dictionary does this use...?

Comment: In a command prompt, read the list of misspellings and suggestions, one of the dictionaries provided with it and/or one you supply.

Comment: This doesn't change filenames, though?